# Dual Link DVI to VGA

Tags: dvi, vga, analog

Well, I have a dual link dvi port graphics card, do I have to use both of these dvi ports to hook up the graphics card to a monitor, or can I just use one?

Comment: Note that you need a [DVI-I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector) output (i.e. it outputs both digital and analog signals) in order to convert it to VGA -- it won't work if the outputs are DVI-D.

Answer (score 1):

One DVI port will be sufficient for driving your display.

You have a graphics card with 2 DVI ports - "Dual Link" is a term used for a single port that has twice as many TDMS pins to support higher resolutions.

[An interesting read on all things DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface)

Answer (score 0):

Only use one cable for the one monitor, if you use both cables on the same monitor you could have some display issues. Simple Awesome! Enjoy Sir!

Comment: You wouldn't have any issues if you connected the seperate ports to seperate ports on the same monitor, e.g DVI1 - VGA and DVI2 - DVI. you could just cycle through the inputs on the monitor. Absolute waste of a cable mind you

Comment: i have actually seen instances before where Windows will only diplay partial desktop images with two hook ups. It got so frequent that i had to put a label on all my new monitors stating " Only plug in one cable *White Or Blue*. People used to call in panic that there machine was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Dual Link DVI means that the port supports a higher bandwidth than a single link DVI

If you are connecting via VGA, Dual link or single link is irrelevant for you

You need to check if the GPU supports DVI-A or DVI-I (post your GPU model if you cannot find that info)

If you are connecting via DVI itself, use the type of cable matching your monitor (if it has a single link DVI, use a single link cable. Else use a dual link cable)

Remember, single and dual link describe the specific port. You do not need to use multiple ports to connect to the monitor

Answer (score 0):

Dual link doesn't matter, what matters is if the DVI port is Digital or Analogue. While that may sound backwards, as DVI stands for Digital Video Interface, it is actually important.

I direct you to this diagram:

http://www.pcmtechcenter.com/images/dvi_connector.jpg

The important part is on the right side of this. You'll note there are 4 pins beside the flat connector. These 4 pins are important to you. If these 4 pins are not present on the female port on your graphics card, it is digital. If the 4 pins ARE present, then it is analogue capable. This is important because if the pins aren't there you will never be able to adapt that port to VGA. If the pins are there, you're in luck! Not only is the adaptor plentiful, but it's also cheap as a result too. Most graphics cards come with them, but if you don't have one, they can be easily bought, example:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814998101